# selecting elements bigger than a particular number in a list

Tags: r, list, subset, apply

I have a list with a big structure similar to this:

```
BigList = 
[[1]]
[1] matrix
[2] array
[3] data.frame
[4] data.frame
[5] integer
[6] character
  ...
[26]

[[2]]
[1] 
  ...
[26]

[[3]]
[1] 
  ...
[26]

[[4]]
...
```

I am trying to get data greater than 10 from element 5 (named "n" in my list) of each list using:

Listsubset = laply(BigList, function(x) x$n[n>10])
Not working

and also use this:

Listsubset = laply(filo_main_data, function(x) x$n >10)
Which worked but gave it to me a result of logical information (TRUE or FALSE) and I would like to get which values of n are TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Filter` :

```
Listsubset <- Filter(function(x) x$n > 10, BigList)
```

Or an alternative with `sapply` :

```
Listsubset <- BigList[sapply(BigList, `[[`, 'n') > 10]
```

Comment: what the operator '[[' means, please?

Comment: @BMT `[[` is to extract value as a vector. Here in each element of `BigList` we extract the element with the name "n" in it as a vector and compare it with 10 (`> 10`). See `?Extract` for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and tips, @Ronak Shah.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply`

```
 BigList[unlist(lapply(BigList, `[[`, "n")) > 10]
```